# Comparing values from two ranges in worksheet and counting the duplicate values

Tags: vba, excel, range

I need to compare values from two ranges in excel sheet and if value found to be equal to another value in the second range I write the number 1 in the cell near to that value and so on increase 1 by the number of each found value.

```
Sub tbl()

  Dim Range1 As Range
  Set Range1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10")
  Dim Range2 As Range
  Set Range2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10")
  Dim cel As Range
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim i, j As Integer

    For j = 1 To Range1.Count


        For i = 1 To Range2.Count

            If Range1(j).Value = Range2(i).Value Then

               x = x + 1
               Dim cel3 As Range
               Set cel3 = Range(Range2(i).Address)
               cel3.Offset(0, 1).Value = x

            End If
        Next i

     Next j
   End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You are not asking a question or telling us the problem with the code above.  Are we supposed to guess as to the problem?

Comment: When you update the question to tell us what problem you are having, also mention which sheet is active when you run the code - is it "Sheet1", "Sheet2", or some other sheet - so that we can tell where you are storing your results.

Comment: The question is that : My code works but it give a wrong result. for example I have in cell(1,1) the value xx and in cell(2,3) the value xx all in the first range and I have the same value in the second range I want to compare and count the cells that have the same value in the first range with the value in the second range and write how many times the same value is counted

Comment: @user3438908 [edit] your question, don't put information that belongs in the OP, in the comments section

Comment: Why don't you just use `COUNTIF`? E.g. assuming your active sheet is Sheet2, put `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$1:$C$10,Sheet2!$A1)` in cell B1 and copy down to cell B10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the values to search into an array and use COUNTIF() on the other range to avoid one of the loops.

```
Sub tbl()

Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Range2 As Variant
Dim range3() As Variant, j As Long

Set Range1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C10")
Range2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10")

ReDim range3(1 To UBound(Range2, 1), 1 To 1)


For j = 1 To UBound(Range2, 1)
    range3(j,1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range1, Range2(j,1))
Next j

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Resize(UBound(range3), 1).Value = range3


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you it works and it just need some correction to feet what I am looking for.

Comment: Scott Craner please how to use your code with  non-contiguous  ranges for          example I have six   non-contiguous  ranges to look in for values

Comment: That is a new question and deserves a new post.

Comment: Okay, I will post a new post